# Sharepoint workflow around the clock

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, time

In the company I work for, we really work around the clock and more... This get particularly noticeable when we use approval workflows in SharePoint document libraries.
If a user in Europe uploads a document, which starts a workflow with an approver in USA, the workflow will be completed before the workflow even was initiated...
At least according to the workflow history.

Example of Workflow History

```
9/11/2019 12:03 AM Workflow Initiated
9/11/2019 9:47 AM Task Completed
9/11/2019 9:47 AM Workflow Completed
```

Is it possible to prevent this kind of "efficiency" to happen in SharePoint? Can the clock be controlled?
Users get confused when they check the workflow history.

Comment: Is it out of the box approval wf or a custom wf?

Comment: It is a standard Approval workflow, out of the box.